# При генерации контроллера в yii2 gii выскакивает ошибка о существовании такой дериктории

Tags: php, yii2, gii

Начал изучать Yii2, но сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой: генерирую с помощью gii контроллер, выскакивает ошибка (она внизу).
Что делал сам:

1. Давал полные права (777) следующим директориям:

   - sudo chmod -R 777 web/assets/
   - sudo chmod -R 777 runtime/
   - sudo chmod -R 777 assets/
2. При удалении из runtime всего кнопка просмотреть срабатывает, но как только в папке появится что-то уже даже generate не срабатывает

Не знаю куда еще копать

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException mkdir(): Файл существует
>
> ```
> 1. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/Generator.php
> ```
>
> at line 246
>       237238239240241242243244245246247248249250251252253254255
>
> ```
>     public function saveStickyAttributes()
>     {
>         $stickyAttributes = $this->stickyAttributes();
>         $stickyAttributes[] = 'template';
>         $values = [];
>         foreach ($stickyAttributes as $name) {
>             $values[$name] = $this->$name;
>         }
>         $path = $this->getStickyDataFile();
>         @mkdir(dirname($path), 0755, true);
>         file_put_contents($path, json_encode($values));
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @return string the file path that stores the sticky attribute values.
>      * @internal
>      */
>     public function getStickyDataFile()
>     {
>
> 2. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/controllers/DefaultController.php
> ```
>
> at line 60 –
>   yii\gii\generators\controller\Generator::saveStickyAttributes()
>       54555657585960616263646566
>
> ```
>         $preview = Yii::$app->request->post('preview');
>         $generate = Yii::$app->request->post('generate');
>         $answers = Yii::$app->request->post('answers');
>
>         if ($preview !== null || $generate !== null) {
>             if ($generator->validate()) {
>                 $generator->saveStickyAttributes();
>                 $files = $generator->generate();
>                 if ($generate !== null && !empty($answers)) {
>                     $params['hasError'] = !$generator->save($files, (array) $answers, $results);
>                     $params['results'] = $results;
>                 } else {
>                     $params['files'] = $files;
>
> 3. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php
> ```
>
> at line 57 – yii\gii\controllers\DefaultController::actionView()
>       4. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php
>   at line 57 –
>   call_user_func_array:{/home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php:57}()
>       5. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php
>   at line 157 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams()
>       6. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php
>   at line 528 – yii\gii\controllers\DefaultController::runAction()
>       7. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php
>   at line 103 – yii\web\Application::runAction()
>       8. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php
>   at line 386 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest()
>       9. in /home/dilun/Projects/Site/4yii2.loc/www/frontend/web/index.php at line
>   17 – yii\web\Application::run()
>       11121314151617
>
> ```
>     require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
>     require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
>     require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
>     require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
> );
>
> (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
> ```
>
> $_GET = [
>       'id' => 'controller', ];
>
> $_POST = [
>       '_csrf-frontend' => 'uSpmlARW7dhFv37BQ7_5BS49mWoe_I5mhup_xBWcsen8fADAcDuXvgfIG5UFx7BIagv7GUGf9C2z0iCOVsXj0Q==',
>       'Generator' => [
>           'controllerClass' => 'app\controllers\TestController',
>           'actions' => 'index test',
>           'viewPath' => '@app/views/test',
>           'baseClass' => 'yii\web\Controller',
>           'template' => 'default',
>       ],
>       'answers' => [
>           'e6187b835bb62a46a2fd6894dbcc98a0' => '1',
>           '39d797e08377bfc4acdc6dd30a5b0c27' => '1',
>           '90002a96fc14f3ac4dac05afb07246c3' => '1',
>       ],
>       'generate' => '', ];
>
> $_COOKIE = [
>       'advanced-frontend' => '0668533ffc4b74935a0f6631ac4a2760',
>       '_csrf-frontend' => '98ef143798901512d85c1a4effb6b991f689a581c564dbbfe0f47fa79af4b4d2a:2:{i:0;s:14:"_csrf-frontend";i:1;s:32:"EVfTtmzfBweTFxIMD6bs_czK58_JCYR8";}',
>   ];
>
> $_SESSION = [
>       '__flash' => [],
>       '__captcha/site/captcha' => 'redira',
>       '__captcha/site/captchacount' => 1, ];
>
> Yii Framework
>
> 2018-01-31, 14:24:35
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.0 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev
>   Perl/v5.16.3
>
> Yii Framework/2.0.13.1